# bibtex sort in alphabetical order with href

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, sorting

I have the following in my references.bib file.

```
@Misc{ref1,
  Title                    = {\href{http://www.ref1.com}{aaa}}
}

@Misc{ref2,
  Title                    = {\href{http://www.ref2.com}{ccc}}
}

@Misc{ref3,
  Title                    = {\href{http://ref3.com}{bbb}}
}
```

How can I sort the bibliography in bibtex to be the following?

```
[1] aaa
[2] bbb
[3] ccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `key` field that's used for sorting:

```
@Misc{ref1,
  key = {aaa},
  Title = {\href{http://www.ref1.com}{aaa}}
}
@Misc{ref2,
  key = {ccc},
  Title = {\href{http://www.ref2.com}{ccc}}
}
@Misc{ref3,
  key = {bbb},
  Title = {\href{http://ref3.com}{bbb}}
}
```

Here's a full example, with `filecontents*` just for making it self-contained.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{ref1,
  key = {aaa},
  Title = {\href{http://www.ref1.com}{aaa}}
}
@Misc{ref2,
  key = {ccc},
  Title = {\href{http://www.ref2.com}{ccc}}
}
@Misc{ref3,
  key = {bbb},
  Title = {\href{http://ref3.com}{bbb}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]